# Auto Saving in JavaMail

Tags: jakarta-mail, autosave

I am working on a simple mail application using JavaMail. My web based mail user agent (MUA) application has the functionality to compose, read, forward, delete, etc mails. Now I want to add a simple functionality that autosaves user's email to a Drafts folder while composing. The user can manually save his/her mail or the application can automatically save to the user's Drafts folder. So, is there a means to achieve this with the help of JavaMail? Or any other better way of achieving this?

Comment: Have db and keep it SENT,DRAFT,INBOX separately for each user

Answer (score 1):

Append the message to the Drafts folder.  You'll have to figure out how to trigger the append from your application.

Comment: that is a better model. I have already a class that appends the message to the Drafts folder and so I have to figure out how I can trigger this from my MUA application. Thanks!